# Search registry in Powershell for specific keys and values within those keys

Tags: powershell, registry, patch

I'm fairly close to a solution, but I just can't get there.  What I'm trying to do is search for installed MS Office updates.  The best way I've found is to search the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` key.

What I then want to do is only look at sub-keys like `*{90140000-001*` (which indicates Office) and the search each found sub-key's DisplayName property for "(KB*" - which will indicate it is an update to Office rather than a component.

What I have so far is this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" -Recurse | Where-Object{$_ -like "*{90140000-001*"} | foreach {
Get-ItemProperty $_.DisplayName}
```

But it produces blank output.

Is anyone able to please help me finish this off?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GetValue` method of the current `RegistryKey` to retrieve the DisplayName:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" -Recurse | 
    Where Name -like '*{90140000-001*' | foreach {
    $_.GetValue("DisplayName")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query remote computers:

```
#config
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$hive = "LocalMachine"

#32-bit Office : SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
#64-bit Office : SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
#Office 2013 : look for keys named "{90140000-001*"
#Office 2016 : look for keys named "{90160000-001*"

$regPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

#if remote computer is reachable
if(Test-Connection $computerName -Quiet -Count 2 -ErrorAction 0) {
    try {
        #open remote registry
        $base = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::$hive, $ComputerName)

        #open desired key with edit permission
        $key = $base.OpenSubKey($regPath)

        foreach($subkeyName in $key.GetSubKeyNames()) {
            if($subkeyName -match "{90160000-001") {
                $subkey = $key.OpenSubKey($subkeyName)
                $displayName = $subkey.GetValue("DisplayName")
                if($displayName -match "\(KB") {
                    $displayName
                }
            }
        }

        #close subkey, key and registry connection
        $subkey.Close()
        $key.Close()
        $base.Close()
    } catch {
        Throw "Remote registry is not accessible (check `$hive and `$regPath, and run this script as administrator)."            
    }
} else {
    Throw "Remote computer is not reachable."
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, all very helpful responses.

Comment: You're welcome. The usage here is to accept the answer you prefer by clicking the check mark next to the answer vote.